# Why is meta refresh redirect no longer working and how can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, bbpress

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

I have a website built in Ruby on Rails. My site has a webpage, located at example.com/communityboard, that you can use to enter a separate Community area (an off-the-shelf bulletin board called bbPress.)

I want users who type in the URL example.com/community to be redirected to example.com/communityboard . It used to work this way, but for some reason, the redirect no longer works in any browser but IE.

We accomplished this redirect by placing an index.html file in the /community folder where bbPress had been installed. The entire code for the index.html file reads

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/communityboard">
```

Back when we built the site, I was told that a meta refresh redirect using an index.html file was the best option. The redirect had to address ONLY a single page (http://example.com/community) and not all of the sublevels of the community bb (which lives at http://example.com/community/index.php). Otherwise, the community bb and all of its sublevels would be redirected.

So... my questions:

Why is the meta refresh redirect not working anymore?
How can I fix it?

Thanks again for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happened according to my developer. I don't fully understand the explanation, so I'm not sure I can answer follow-up questions! "With the old mongrel cluster, Apache would recognize "/community" as a directory, silently forward to "/community/", which would then pick up the forwarding index.html file. With Phusion Passenger," which I guess we're using now, "Apache sends the request directly to Passenger if "/community" is not a regular file, and Passenger was returning the 404 error. As a fix, we've disabled passenger in the community folder, which fixes the problem."

Answer (score 0):

If it's only working in IE, it's possible there's a script or parsing issue that's breaking other browsers. I would run the HTML through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/.

Meta-refresh is a legacy practice that is now discouraged -- the wikipedia entry contains more info and links to alternative solutions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh.

Comment: Tx, mcknz. Checked /community and /community/index.html. Some errors, but don't think they are related. Community results in a 404 error. Its error document has 3 errors, all dealing with the meta description. For Index.html, "mismatch between Public and System identifiers in the DOCTYPE declaration". "This document uses an inconsistent DOCTYPE declaration." Missing xmlns attribute for element html. Value should be: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` Open to alternatives to meta-refresh, but redirect has to address ONLY a single page (http://example.com/community) and not sublevels of the bb.

Comment: Instead of adding an index.html file with meta-refresh, can you use a PHP file as the default document in "example.com/community" and do a server-side redirect? That should eliminate any browser differences.

Comment: We have a file at example.com/community/index.php and a file at example.com/community/index.html. HTML meta-refresh redirects. PHP serves as the top level of the community board. The problem seems to be that when you enter "example.com/community" (no /index.html or /index.php), you get a 404 error. It's not picking up either of the files. What do you think?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is maybe the site's configured to look for a different default document, other than index.

Comment: For some reason, the site is now working as intended! I'm going to try and find out next week how it happened and will report here.

Comment: Here's what happened according to my developer. I don't fully understand the explanation, so I'm not sure I can answer follow-up questions! "With the old mongrel cluster, Apache would recognize "/community" as a directory, silently forward to "/community/", which would then pick up the forwarding index.html file. With Phusion Passenger," which I guess we're using now, "Apache sends the request directly to Passenger if "/community" is not a regular file, and Passenger was returning the 404 error. As a fix, we've disabled passenger in the community folder, which fixes the problem."

Comment: Great, glad it's fixed -- post your comment as an answer and accept it, so others can benefit if they have a similar problem.